# Convert a cURL API call to Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest, curl

```
curl --basic --user {username}:{password} https://www.blueworkslive.com/api/Auth
```

I have tried to write something like this but it won't work! I keep getting error `400`

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "https://www.blueworkslive.com/api/Auth",
     type: "GET", //This is what you should chage
     dataType: "jsonp",
     username: "admin", // Most SAP web services require credentials
     password: "admin",
     processData: false,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function () {
         alert("success");
         console.log("success");
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         console.log("error");
         console.log(xhr.responseText);
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(xhr.responseText);
     },
 });
```

And this as well: 
{$(document).ready(function() {
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
        xhr.open("GET", "https://www.blueworkslive.com/api/Auth?version=20091212", false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username.com:password"));
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        xhr.send("");

        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
```

});}
 Error: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I assumed the error was caused due to me running the script from a local server (since the origin was set to null by default) so I deployed it on a app development server so that I had a public origin.The same error occurred for the new origin - even though the origin now was not null anymore but the server provided origin!

Comment: @blackpla9ue did you add the comments with your edit?

Comment: @devnull69 nope. only indentations. check edit history.

Comment: Interesting ... during my attempt to edit I was presented with "your" edit showing the added comments, now I can see from history that this change was done before

Comment: Isn't calling another site in AJAX generally forbidden? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting  So it would work from cURL but not from a Javascript call.

Comment: I tried to use jsonp which I think is not subject to these security constrains. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(function (){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://www.blueworkslive.com/api/Auth', // url checked ...// error 400 not found url
                    data: { 
                        //data
                        username:username,
                        email:email
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        //result success
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.